# Nifi user create and delete logs info

Tags: logging, apache-nifi

I need to show some log when I create or delete user on Nifi.

- Which user **created** or **deleted** and who was done it.
- Witch **permission** gives and who was gives it.

I change the log level with debug to show these in **nifi-user.log**, but still I can not see this information in there.

How can reach these logs, could you please give some advice?